# Sound Not working in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: dual-boot

Please help me, I have tried everything but still sound is not working on my ubuntu 11.10. I am new to ubuntu. Searched everywhere then i finally decided to ask a question here . Hope someone can help me!!

Comment: What is your laptop make/model?

Answer (score 0):

Please install **Ubuntu Restricted Extras** from Software Centre. Ofcourse you have to tick the checkboxes for Software as well as Source code in the Software Updates before proceeding to download the software mentioned.
I think what you mean by not being able to play sounds is you are not able to play mp3's.

Answer (score 0):

Try in Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

(You should be connected to Internet, without any proxy.)

You can also diretly download vlc player from Ubuntu Software Center. VLC will play everything.